# How can I call a function inside the GUI interface independently to any callback function?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, interface, matlab-guide

I have a artificial vision aplication and now I want to program a user interface that can show the client the image processed that the camera is taking. The image showed in the interface is constantly changing without any user interaction (without pushing any button ) and I don't know how to change images from the GUI without any user interaction.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is the 3rd time you post the same, relatively vague, question (which is _too broad_ for this webiste in my opinion). I suggest you read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), delete 2 of your questions, then edit and reformulate one of them in a way which will allow (and motivate) people to help you. Good luck!

Comment: Your other similar questions: [How to programme a main function inside a GUI interface with button callbacks working as interruptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55892043/how-to-programme-a-main-function-inside-a-gui-interface-with-button-callbacks-wo) and [User interface with GUI and callbacks working as interrupction in a main function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55891925/user-interface-with-gui-and-callbacks-working-as-interrupction-in-a-main-functio)